# A word for a joke so poorly told and so unfunny that one cannot help but laugh

Tags: single-word-requests, translation, expression-choice

There is a word for this in Indonesian language: **jayus**.

(Maybe, it is used in Filipino and Malaysian language also.)

It is a joke that is so bad, it's funny. It is often mentioned as untranslatable. I wonder if there is any English equivalent though. (and yes, English does not have to have a word for everything but there is always a chance or we can find a close match at least.)

---

**Lame joke** is mentioned in some of the sources but it does not quite fit. Here is an explanation:

> Some argue that “lame joke” would do just fine, but not all lame jokes can make one laugh. A joke becomes a jayus when those who heard it laughed, not at the joke but at the person’s failed attempt to deliver a punch line. 
>   <sub>Source: [~](http://otherwordlyblog.wordpress.com/tag/jayus/)</sub>

Comment: A mazel tough ?

Comment: A dad joke? Phrase I use a lot..

Comment: "Car crash" and "Train wreck" are common metaphors for awful things that attract attention and fascination. If someone told a spectacularly bad joke and people fell about laughing at the awkwardness, you could say something like "That joke was a car crash, mate". But it's not specific to jokes.

Comment: @TyrantWave - My kids use that expression, too. :^)

Comment: It was so funny that I forgot to laugh

Comment: @TyrantWave From the OP's link: "a person [...] who always tells weird unfunny jokes and the student [...] tried to laugh every time he tells a joke, long after that, the student are laughing at the teacher not with the teacher. They laugh [at] how someone could create such [a] weird or lame story in the spirit of humoring." Really makes me think that "Dad joke" is better than any of the other answers given so far. Worth expanding your comment into an answer IMO.

Comment: @starsplusplus Done :).

Comment: I saw this called an "Anti-Joke" on another post

Comment: I believe the important distinction is the **"at the person’s failed attempt to deliver a punch line"**.  English doesn't really have anything like this.  Everything close is in reference to the joke.

Comment: I usually call them "jokes" since they're pretty much the only ones I ever tell.

Comment: I call them puns.

Comment: Is the badness of the joke intended/known by the one telling it?

Comment: @steveverrill an anti-joke is deliberately so, especially if it plays with a familiar form, like "Knock Knock!", "Who's there?" "Orange" "Orange who?" "Orange you glad I didn't say 'there's been an accident. I'm so sorry. I– I– Do you need a lift to the hospital? I can– Oh god, I'm so sorry'" or "Make like a banana and slowly blacken and turn to mush".

Comment: @cobaltduck you should post your suggestion, it's as good as any of the ones posted so far. A groaner is a corny joke which induces a fake pained expression in the listener/victim, which in turn might lead to giggles or even hilarity.

Comment: I'm delighted that Indonesian has a word for it. I love killing jokes and do it regularly in my lessons by over-explaining each meaning of the word in a pun whilst letting my enthusiasm drop slowly, ending with a rather deflated and quiet "so, ah, so, since the word can be interpreted either way, er, ... it's a .... it's a pun, you see, so, er ... so therefore ..... funny." Often my students laugh at how poorly I have told the joke, but always I find the head shaking, winces, stoney reception and/or objections hilarious and struggle to keep a straight face making the joke less and less funny.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is **anti-joke**, from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-humor):

> Anti-humor is a type of indirect humor that involves the joke-teller delivering something 
>       which is deliberately not funny, or lacking in intrinsic meaning. The practice relies on
>       the expectation on the part of the audience of something humorous, and when this does not
>       happen, the irony itself is of comedic value. Anti-humor is also the basis of various
>       types of pranks and hoaxes

Comment: This could be a good answer if you took some relevant parts of the wiki article (or other places where anti-humor is discussed), and pasted them in a “quote box” to bolster your suggestion.

Comment: I don't think this fits because it describes the type of joke more than the audience's reaction. Anti-humor is intentionally designed by the joke teller to be ironically "bad", while jayus is the joke teller's failure to make the audience laugh for the right reasons.

Comment: Wikipedia says "something which is deliberately not funny, **or lacking in intrinsic meaning.**". So does it mean it sometimes happens naturally and it does not need to be setup? I couldn't find much detail about this though.

Comment: To me an anti joke is something like "why are there no aspirin in the jungle?" (A widely known children's joke that sets up the expectation of the punch line "because the parrots eat them all") but then delivering a punchline like the following...

Comment: [Well, the lack of pharmacists/chemists in true 'jungle' areas means that they can't be purchased there, which will limit numbers. However, statistically some will be mistakenly left by explorers or other visitors to the area as Aspirin is useful in the jungle as an analgesic to relieve minor aches and pains, as an antipyretic to reduce fever, and as an anti-inflammatory medication, as well as having an anti-coagulate effect.](http://killingthejoke.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/why-are-there-no-aspirin-in-jungle.html)

Comment: Maybe this does not cover exactly but I think anti-joke is the closest one.

Answer (score 40):

**So bad, it's good** is often used in reference to movies like this, but can also apply to comedians or any other entertainment, and presumably a joke.

Example usage:

> *Troll 2* is one of those so-bad-it's-good movies.

_

> I just watched *Troll 2* it was so bad it was good.

Within the context of telling a joke you could say something like:

> Alvin is terrible joke teller, the way he told the joke was so bad it was good.

or simply

> That joke was so bad, it was good.

Comment: A _movie_ that's so bad that it makes people laugh (_at_ it, not _with_ it) may be referred to as _camp_. I don't think I've heard that term applied to a joke, though.

Comment: Is this answer better than "so bad, it's funny"? Because I mentioned this in the question.

Comment: @PhilPerry Being camp is but one of the possible ways a movie can be so bad that it's good. Not all unintentionally hilarious films are camp.

Comment: Obligatory xkcd reference that supports this answer: http://xckd.com/653/

Answer (score 22):

A phrase that's often used would be a **dad joke**.

(nb: You don't need to be a dad to make one, as my S.O. likes to remind me with my jokes...)

Any joke that's so abysmal such that it makes people groan could fall under this. Essentially, think of any joke your dad would make.

> Dad, I'm hungry!
>   Hi Hungry, I'm dad!

Also, jokes with a buildup you just *know* it's going to suck, but you can't help but laugh because of it. And so on.

Comment: But that's not a bad joke.Maybe you won't laugh because you are hungry,but you have to admit,it's funny.

Answer (score 6):

Corny joke might be what you're after.

Comment: Isn't this same as lame jock? You can give more details also.

Comment: This is a good answer, give us some examples please. I would have suggested this one, myself. I'm thinking of those cringing "jokes" or puns that one finds in Christmas crackers.

Comment: The OP's explanation indicates that it includes bad telling of the joke messing up the joke, which doesn't really fit under "corny joke".

Answer (score 4):

As requested in the comments, I am providing *[groaner](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/groaner)* as an answer.

Occasionally, a person will tell a joke, and when he gets to the punchline, the listeners realize that they have been suckered.  It ends with an anti-climax, a horrible pun, or some other unexpectedly un-funny result.

The reaction is then a cross between a laugh and a groan.  On the one hand, you have disgust over the joke, yet an acknowledgement that it does have a certain bit of wit behind it.  You also simultaneously have the sense of shame-on-you toward the joke-teller for taking you in, while also giving credit for having done so, a sort of "Aha, you got me." kind of moment.

Comment: I'm not aware I've ever actually heard "groaner" used like this, but there's no doubt that [***groanworthy***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E2%80%9Cgroanworthy%E2%80%9D&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) almost always applies to jokes, rarely anything else.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase **laughing at him not with him** works in a lot of these cases.

Answer (score 2):

In many parts of Europe this is referred to as a *Polish joke*, but it isn't commonly known in other parts of the world.

Comment: That is awesome... it's a recursive joke.

Comment: Jokeception @Jasmine

Answer (score 2):

I think that [**train wreck**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/train_wreck) (in American English) or **car crash** (in British English) is the best phrase to use for this. It suggests that something's so bad that it's entertaining.

Answer (score 2):

Something *very* close to this is the [shaggy dog story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaggy_dog_story). An extremely brief synopsis of the archetypal shaggy dog story is as follows (quoted [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaggy_dog_story#The_archetypal_shaggy_dog_story)).

> A boy owned a dog that was uncommonly shaggy. Many people remarked upon its considerable shagginess. When the boy learned that there are contests for shaggy dogs, he entered his dog. The dog won first prize for shagginess in both the local and the regional competitions. The boy entered the dog in ever-larger contests, until finally he entered it in the world championship for shaggy dogs. When the judges had inspected all of the competing dogs, they remarked about the boy's dog: "He's not that shaggy."

The specific events in the story might change every time you tell the story; it's more like a template for improvisation than a set narrative. Properly told, this story could last five, ten, or even fifteen minutes. You can imagine the anticlimax at the end. The teller, leading up to it, might begin to feign repressed giggles, cover his or her mouth for a moment, and generally behave as if the coming punchline is the funniest thing imaginable.

This doesn't seem to be a *perfect* translation, since the kinds of jokes you're talking about might not be that long; a shaggy dog story is almost always long. Still, the concept seems quite similar to me.

Comment: Interesting.  I viewed the wiki, but I had always heard that the origin of this term was a story of a very destitute man seeing signs around town, "Lost, shaggy dog, reward $25,000" and then soon finding one shaggy dog.  The story teller then takes you through many mis-adventures the man has getting to the address on the signs, with the man persevering due to the chance to finally get back on his feet and out of his misery via the reward money.  When he knocks on the door, the person who answers says, "That's not our dog."

Comment: @cobaltduck, I think it would be impossible to pick out one "authentic, original" shaggy dog story. It's more like a template for improvisation. I've never heard the version you're describing, but the idea seems roughly the same.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if we have a word for it, but we certainly have a well known phrase to describe the reaction:

> You have to laugh, or else you'd cry...

Answer (score 1):

It's the *[laughing-stock](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/laughing-stock)* – so bad, it's funny.

> someone or something that seems stupid or silly, especially by trying to be serious or important and not succeeding

An invention of the Bard himself.

Comment: Hmm this new answer is a promising candidate also. But isn't it used mainly for someone who is laughed at in general? We can say "he is a joke" also in this sense. So here, laughing stock itself becomes a joke but not the joke that is told. Wow this is like an enigma.

Comment: @ermanen  "isn't it used mainly for someone who is laughed at in general?" -- No, that's the common error of interpreting 'stock' as we do in the kitchen. See the 'especially' qualifier in the definition.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the closest term I've heard used is simply a "bad joke", but said in a manner that implied it was funny nonetheless. So not so much a word as an implication in speech.

I've also heard them referred to as "dry", although that's not correct and I believe was said in error.

Answer (score 0):

I think **flub** could work.

> The comedian stunk, but he flubbed his jokes so bad, we were rolling in the aisles anyway.

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flub

Comment: You can flub a perfectly good joke though, and while flubbing any kind of joke might sometimes be funny for the audience, it can certainly provoke more negative reactions too.

Answer (score -3):

What about schlemoozel? It would come from Schlemazel  http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=schlemazel

Answer (score -4):

I think it should be 'poor joke'/PJ. It is a very commonly used phrase.