# Is there a word in English for a joke that isn't funny?

Tags: single-word-requests

There are words like dad joke, lame joke, pj (poor joke) for a joke that isn't funny at all.

Is there a **single word** for such jokes that are not amusing?

Comment: **anti-joke** or [anti-humor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-humor) is a type of indirect humor that involves the joke-teller delivering something which is deliberately not funny.

Comment: **non-joke** is a story, utterance, etc. that is not a joke. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nonjoke)

Comment: Q: is "dad joke" a typo of "dud joke"?

Comment: @agc No. It's a stereotype of fathers to make awful puns.

Comment: TROLLING: deliberate anti-humor presented as a joke to get a ride out of the audience.  The older I get, the more I feel "Fred Bassett" is just trolling me.

Comment: related: [A word for a joke so poorly told and so unfunny that one cannot help but laugh](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/168557/a-word-for-a-joke-so-poorly-told-and-so-unfunny-that-one-cannot-help-but-laugh)

Comment: That was a dud. Another possibility is clunker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there's no such single word; however, the idiomatic expression ***damp squib*** can be effectively used to denote a failed joke.

From [WORDCRAFT DICTIONARY](http://wordcraft.infopop.cc/dictionary/part4.htm):

> **damp squib** – *a failed joke*

From [urbandictionary.com](http://fr.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=damp%20squib):

> **damp squib**
>
> A type of firework (squib) that has become wet (damp). Basically, a
> dissapointment.

From [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/damp_squib).:

> **damp squib** ‎(plural damp squibs)
>
> A firework that fails to go off, due to wetting.
>
> (idiomatic, by
> extension) Anything that doesn’t work properly, or fails to come up to
> expectations.